# How to get asp:LoginName to show the form UserId rather than the Windows UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've just been going through the following tutorial https://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/08/creating-an-asp-net-login-screen/ to create a basic login to an area of my asp.net website.

In the tutorial I am told to create LogIn.aspx to my main project and a folder called Members containing within it Members.aspx and a Web.Config file.

The Members Web.Config file is set as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Within the Main Web.Config for the site I am told to replace the `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` with the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/members/member.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Within the LogIn.aspx I have the following asp form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>LogIn Page</h2>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please log in below to access the membership area."></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Login ID="LoginControl" runat="server" 
            onauthenticate="LoginControl_Authenticate">
        </asp:Login>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Within the Member.aspx I have the following form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Membership Page</h2>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Welcome "></asp:Label>
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName" runat="server" />
        (<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/default.aspx" />)
    </div>
</form>
```

Hitting the login triggers some code that authenticates the username and password against a database and if all is well triggers the following: `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)`.

Everything seems to be working bar the fact that When I am redirected to the Member page, the `asp:LoginName` is resolving to my Windows User, not to the user who was authenticated in the Login Page. Any idea how I make sure that the Windows User is ignored, and that I only pick up on the user who logged in via the LogIn page?

For completeness here is the code that is used to authenticate:

```
    Private Function ValidateCredentials(userName As String, password As String) As Integer

        Dim returnValue As Integer = -2

        If (IsAlphaNumeric(userName) And userName.Length <= 50 And password.Length <= 50) Then
            Dim conn As IngresConnection
            conn = New IngresConnection With {.ConnectionString = My.Settings.MembershipSiteConStr}

            Try

                Dim Sql As String() = {
                    "update dsar_users SET last_attempt=sysdate where userid = @username",
                    "update dsar_users SET locked=true where userid = @username and login_attempts >= 3",
                    "update dsar_users SET login_attempts=0 where userid = @username and pword = hash(@password)",
                    "update dsar_users SET login_attempts=login_attempts+1 where userid = @username and pword != hash(@password)",
                    "select 
                      case 
                       when reset=false and locked=false and pword = hash(@password) then 1
                       when reset=true and locked=false and pword = hash(@password) then 2
                       when locked=true then -1
                       else 0
                      end as result
                    from dsar_users where userid = @username"
                    }

                Dim User As New IngresParameter
                User.ParameterName = "@username"
                User.Value = userName.Trim()

                Dim pass As New IngresParameter
                pass.ParameterName = "@password"
                pass.Value = password.Trim()

                Dim cmd As New IngresCommand
                cmd = conn.CreateCommand

                With cmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.Add(User)
                    .Parameters.Add(pass)
                    .Connection = conn
                End With

                conn.Open()

                For i = 0 To 4
                    cmd.CommandText = Sql(i)
                    If i < 4 Then
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Else
                        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar
                    End If
                Next

            Catch exception As Exception
                returnValue = -2

                ' Log your error

            Finally
                If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    conn.Close()
                End If
            End Try

        Else
            returnValue = -3
        End If

        Return returnValue

    End Function
    Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim authenticated As Integer
        authenticated = ValidateCredentials(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password)

        Select Case authenticated
            Case -3
                Login1.FailureText = "You ENTERED SOMETHING WEIRD"
            Case -2
                Login1.FailureText = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG"
            Case -1
                Login1.FailureText = "YOU'RE ACCOUNT HAS BEEN LOCKED"
            Case 0
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
            Case 1
                'FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)
                Session("DSARUser") = Login1.UserName
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, False)
                'FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("herklotj", False)
            Case 2
                Login1.FailureText = "YOU NEED TO UPDATE YOU'RE PASSWORD"
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Small update - the asp:LoginName seems to randomly change between using the windows login user and the form login user. If I keep logging out and then in again, it will  sometimes display one, sometimes the other!

Comment: where are you setting LoginName? Show that code

Comment: @JobesK I'm not - this seems to be an automatic variable. From the Tutorial: _"The message we are displaying on screen contains the user’s login name. The system stored the user’s name automatically when he logged in, and we are using the LoginName control to display it on the page."_. It is this control then that is flip flopping between by Windows User and my form User

Comment: LoginControl_Authenticate can you show that code?

Comment: @JobesK Just added to the original post.

Comment: Session("DSARUser") session variable are you using that anywhere?

Comment: Yes - I was using it as a test to show that Login.Username was correct - so I added the following code in the Page Load section of the Members Page: `Dim DSARUser As String = CType(Session.Item("DSARUser"), String)
        Label2.Text = DSARUser` This always shows the correct form User - however I still want to understand why the asp:LoginName is inconsistant.